# How do I use Hmisc::latex()

Tags: r, latex, tabular, hmisc, reproducible-research

Hmisc::latex() seems to ignore all the arguments I give it, other than `object`.  It's hard to point to a specific question I need answered, other than -- "How can I get Hmisc::latex()" to recognize the arguments its documentation says it should?

For example, these two commands produce the same output:

```
library(Hmisc)
library(tables)

t <- tabular(Species ~ (Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)*(mean + sd), data = iris)

latex(object = t)
latex(object = t, booktabs = TRUE, align = rep('r', 5))
```

The output I get from both of these commands is:

```
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sepal.Length} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sepal.Width} \\ 
Species  & mean & sd & mean & \multicolumn{1}{c}{sd} \\ 
\hline
setosa  & $5.006$ & $0.3525$ & $3.428$ & $0.3791$ \\
versicolor  & $5.936$ & $0.5162$ & $2.770$ & $0.3138$ \\
virginica  & $6.588$ & $0.6359$ & $2.974$ & $0.3225$ \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

I am using Hmisc 4.0-2 and tables 0.8 on R 3.2.2.

Edit: the `caption` and `caption.loc` arguments seem to be ignored as well.  But if I run `booktabs()` prior to running `latex()`, that does take effect (changes the formatting of the table).

Comment: I don't use this package, but I'm pretty satisfied with the `xtable` package in terms of formatting. Much of the formatting there is done with the `print.xtable` function, so perhaps there is a similar method with `Hmisc`.

Comment: I love `xtable`, but in this case I need to generate a table with a sort of 'nested' structure, so the formula options from `tabular` are a huge help.  (I also need to make ~ 8 such tables and may need to re-make them a few times.)

Answer (score 1):

@rcorty from two days ago -- you are misunderstanding what `R` does when you call `latex()` on your object of class `tabular`.  You believe that it's running `Hmisc::latex()`, the default S3 method for the `latex` generic.  But what's really happening is `R` is running `tables::latex()`, the S3 method for objects of class `tabular`, which is the class of the objects you have.

Have a look at the documentation for `tables::latex()` and you'll see what arguments you can use.

Though, it is a bit weird that you're not getting any error about unused arguments.